# Pyqtgraph color specific regions in plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I've been using matplotlib.collections up until now and it was fairly simple to mark a collection with a different color.

My current project requires me to use pyqtgraph to do the same.

```
self.plot = pg.PlotWidget()
layout.addWidget(self.plot)
```

If the index i of bool array is true then that corresponding index i of float has to be colored (vertically or broken horizontal bars).

Example:

```
y = [50, 100, 50, 250, 150]
x = [1, 5, 87, 92, 106]
b = [False, False, True, False, True]
```

After plotting 87 and 106 should be highlighted through vertical bars over x axis with some color or mark. Any hints?

Comment: BUMP. Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Have a look at `LinearRegionItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on the visualization you have in mind, but here are a couple of options for marking your selected points:

1. Use a single instance of `pg.VTickGroup` to draw ticks along the x axis
2. Use many instances of `pg.InfiniteLine` to draw lines and other marking shapes

Example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

plt = pg.plot()

y = [50, 100, 50, 250, 150]
x = [1, 5, 87, 92, 106]
b = [False, False, True, False, True]

# draw a scatter plot with selected points in yellow
cmap = {False: (0, 0, 200), True: (255, 255, 0)}
brushes = [pg.mkBrush(cmap[x]) for x in b]
plt.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol='o', symbolBrush=brushes)

# draw vertical ticks marking the position of selected points
tick_x = np.array(x)[b]
ticks = pg.VTickGroup(tick_x, yrange=[0, 0.1], pen={'color': 'w', 'width': 5})
plt.addItem(ticks)

# add a vertical line with marker at the bottom for each selected point
for tx in tick_x:
    l = plt.addLine(x=tx, pen=(50, 150, 50), markers=[('^', 0, 10)])
```

Comment: Your answer is kinda right. But not something I had in mind. After looking at your approach, I looked at LinearRegionItem. It's very fast, works with bounds (left limit and right limit) and gets the job done well, does not make it difficult to see the data, which Infinite line does. Anyway, thanks for your answer, I'm not marking as correct answer, but I will give you the bounty.